# Calculating Pi with Taylor Method

Tags: c++, pi, taylor-series

Instructions:

> An approximate value of pi can be calculated using the series given below:
>
> pi = 4 * [ 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 … + ((-1)^n)/(2n + 1) ]
>
> write a C++ program to calculate the approximate value of pi using this series. The program takes an input n that determines the number of terms in the approximation of the value of pi and outputs the approximation. Include a loop that allows the user to repeat this calculation for new values n until the user says she or he wants to end the program.

Attempt:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()  

{
    //declare variables
    double sum, pi;
    int n;
    
    //prompt user
    cout << "How many decimals would you like to calculate pi to? ";
    cin >> n;
    
    //calculate pi
    
    //print response
    cout << fixed << setprecision (n) << pi << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The *cmath* and *math.h* are leftover from attempts to make what I was given work properly and it solved a few of my errors but I know I really need to do more. I assume I need loops somehow since that's where I am in class but I don't know what to loop. How should I implement the series?

Comment: SO is for specific questions not conversations or pointers!

Answer (score 5):

Someone already did the calculus for you by giving that series sum.  You need a function; something like this:

```
double pi(int n) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    int sign = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {           
        sum += sign/(2.0*i+1.0);
        sign *= -1;
    }
    return 4.0*sum;
}
```

Taylor series *isn't* very accurate: 10,000 terms and the approximation is `3.1414926535900345`.  A million terms and the approximation is `3.1415916535897743`.  A hundred million terms and the approximation is `3.141592643589326`.

Not very good.

Comment: Where does term come in?

Comment: changed my mind; i'll remove it.

Comment: @duffymo add a remark that, using your function, the `setprecision()` at the end should be set according to the accuracy of the result, i.e. 3 digits after the decimal point

Comment: Yeah I removed it when I better understood the prompt based on the answers given here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the nth term of a Taylor series is done by calculating `((-1)^n)/(2n + 1)`. To calculate up to the nth term, you should then loop from 0 to n, adding up the final result to your current approximation of pi at the end of each loop.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a series is that the bigger the n, the more accurate the value is. So if you simply make this code and run for n=2, it will be totally wrong. You can either recursive, or simple. I'll give it the simple way

```
double partialSeries = 0d;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) // you give the value to n
   if (i % 2 == 0)
       partialSeries += 1/(2.0 * i + 1);
   else
       partialSeries -= 1/(2.0 * i + 1);
double series = 4 * partialSeries;
```